# Css column ordering

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Hi all,

I have a design like an image and used bootstrap 5 for coding.  I want to carry the sticky div area from the number one to the first div after on mobile. I can't use js. I tried to use CSS flexbox order but how can ı do that with only CSS?

I look forward to your ideas and suggestions.
Thank you so much!

```css
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 600px;
}
.box  {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size:92px;
}
.box:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: #A7A7A7;
    height: 232px;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: #A7A7A7;
    height: 250px;
}
.box:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #A7A7A7;
    height: 500px;
}
.sticky {
    background-color: #DDBEBE;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="box">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="sticky">
                    sticky area
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is achieveable with flexbox alone.
However, I managed to address your requirements with `display: grid` and some fiddling with `grid-area`s on the elements. This solution also defines a specific `grid-template` per screen resolution.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "box1 sticky"
    "box2 sticky"
    "box3 sticky";
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "box1"
      "sticky"
      "box2"
      "box3";
  }
}
```

The caveat here is that each element has to have its dedicated `grid-area` value for the template, so won't work for the cases where you don't know the exact number of containers in play or such number is unreasonably high.

Hope this helps!

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 600px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 92px;
}

.box:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #A7A7A7;
  height: 232px;
  grid-area: box1;
}

.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #A7A7A7;
  height: 250px;
  grid-area: box2;
}

.box:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #A7A7A7;
  height: 500px;
  grid-area: box3;
}

.sticky {
  order: 1;
  background-color: #DDBEBE;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  grid-area: sticky;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "box1 sticky"
    "box2 sticky"
    "box3 sticky";
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "box1"
      "sticky"
      "box2"
      "box3";
  }
  
  .sticky {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">
      sticky area
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```